# Assert that no values are selected from dropdown list with selenium IDE

Tags: ajax, selenium

I have this scenario: simple `HTML` form that is being processed with Ajax with clear (reset that form) button. I want to test clear function, hence the question:  What is the right way to check that no values are selected from `drop-down` list with Selenium IDE?

I've tried `assertSelectedValue` command but didn't find a way to specify the unselected value. So I switched to `assertValue` command which works smooth with input fields and checkboxes. But is it right to use it for dropdown lists? Even though test passes with specified `dropdown` list id as a target and blank field as a value, I still can't get rid of a feeling something is wrong.

Any clarification is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit late, but generally an attribute is provided selected="selected" to the option when an option is chosen. This would especially be applicable when using a multi-select combobox, where no options could be selected also.

So to test if no option is selected, perform something like this:

```
verifyElementNotPresent   
xpath=//select[@id="xxx"]/option[@selected="selected"]
```

If no options are selected, the output is true, otherwise false.

For reporting you can use `storeElementNotPresent`.
Instead of `verifyElementNotPresent`, you can also use `assertElementNotPresent`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I'm a couple of months late, but in case you're still thinking on this:

I'm not sure which the code in your dropdown list is. But any html dropdown has always a value selected.

For example with this html:

```
<select>
  <option>Please select a value</option>
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</select>
```

your test will be:

```
assertSelectedValue | "locator" | Please select a value |
```

in case your select has an empty first option, you can just leave the last column empty:

```
<select>
  <option></option>
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</select>
```

your test will be:

```
assertSelectedValue | "locator" |  |
```

Answer (score 0):

Several months late, but if anyone else needs this:

```
assertNotSomethingSelected | "locator" | |
```

Comment: Finally, something that works! Thank you, even late.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential answer for you.

You have the following code snippet:

```
<select>
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

And you want to check on the name of the auto and not the value for the option.

You'll want to use :

```
assertSelectedLabel | "locator" |  |
```